# .net core 500 internal server error after adding new api controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a .net core application which currently has one api controller and everything works fine. The problem is when I add another api controller to the solution with a different name and route. If I try to to run the APIs I get 500 internal server error once I add another controller.
If I remove the newly added api controller everything works fine again.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the OS' Event Log.  It should be able to give you more information about exactly what failed.

Comment: Try Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution, also, if you are using IIS, try restarting the application

Comment: maybe code will help

Comment: Tried cleaning, rebuilding and restarting the solution, did not help! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is with the name (Name = "Get") attribute added to HttpGet method was the problem. All the controllers had the same Name attribute and hence the error. Removing the Name attribute from controllers solved the problem.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```